# How to copy files flattening into one dir using find and xargs (GNU Bash)

Tags: bash, find, gnu

I need to find all files (e.g. with extension ABC) and copy it into one directory but creating unique filenames not to overwrite any files with the potential same name.

Something like this:

```
find /tmp -name \*.ABC | xargs cp '{}' somedir/$(echo {} | md5sum | cut -c1-6){} \;
```

Creating files like:

```
b786af1_original_name.ABC
a7af335_original_name_2.ABC
...
```

The command above obviously cannot work because $( ... ) statement is getting evaluated once. I need to evaluate it for every file name.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not [read](http://linux.die.net/man/1/read)?

```
find /tmp -name \*.ABC | while read i; do cp $i $(basename $i | md5sum | cut -c1-6)$(basename $i); done;
```

Comment: But you'll also have to read up on find -0 and quoting "$i" to handle filenames with spaces

Comment: Sounds promising! I know -0 together with xargs but I am not sure how to handle it in read. Gotta find it but I have a direction now.

Comment: Well I dont have spaces in my case. Going on without -0. It solved my problem. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you in the future need a solution that accepts even \n in file names try: `for find /tmp -name \*.ABC -print0 | parallel -0 'cp {} $(echo {/} | md5sum | cut -c1-6){/}'`

Answer (score 1):

How about a random int based on the current nanosecond?

```
date +%N | sed -e 's/000$//' -e 's/^0//'
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#  Strip off leading and trailing zeroes, if present.
#  Length of generated integer depends on
#  + how many zeroes stripped off.
```

Probability of getting the same file with the same name is very small with this method.

Source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html

EDIT: actually this will just give you the same problem. Does it need to be a one liner?

Comment: Yes thanks. I already tried this with the same result. No need of one-liner. Not at all!

Comment: Upvoting for trying this out for me. But solution is above. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here's a weird-filename-proofed version of @Ken's answer:

```
find /tmp -name \*.ABC -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' i; do cp "$i" "$(basename "$i" | md5sum | cut -c1-6)$(basename "$i")"; done
```

See [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for details, variants, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mktemp` to generate unique names:

```
find /tmp -name \*.ABC | while read f; do 
  cp "$f" "$(mktemp /destination/dir/XXXXXXXXXX.ABC)"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Important sidenote:  watch out how big of a part of a hash you're using as an identifier.

If you're using 6 values of 0..F (16 values), that's less than 17 million combinations.  So if you have 5000 files that you're identifying with these, you got a 52% chance of having a collision.  7 hex chars yields 4.5%, and 8 hex chars yields 0.3% of collision (for the 5000 files).